# Making video fullscreen automatically when the device orientation is landscape with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, video, orientation, fullscreen

I have a video that if you press a button it becomes fullscreen. I need help making the video fullscreen automatically when the device is in landscape orientation. I have tried many ways but none have worked.

Here is my code:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("video");

function becomeFullscreen() {
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    /* Firefox */
    elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
    /* IE/Edge */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}
```

```html
<video id="video" width="600" height="800">
            <source src="videoplaceholder.mp4" />
        </video>

<button id="button" onclick="becomeFullscreen()">Fullscreen</button>
```

Comment: Please let us know if there is any code you have tried  to check the device and it's in landscape mode or not.

Comment: I have tried this code:     window.addEventListener("orientationchange",function() {
                    becomeFullscreen();
                },
                false
            );

Comment: You need to check the window.orientation property inside the orientationChange handler, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/orientation

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll read that

Comment: Thanks its working now!

Comment: I have added this as Answer, please mark it as answer. Other may find this usefull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the window.orientation property inside the orientationChange handler. Inside the event handler of orientationChange event, check the window.screen.orientation property. If it's landscape make video fullscreen.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/orientation

Answer (score 3):

Add below code in your JavaScript:

```js
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function(event) {
  var orientation = (window.screen.orientation || {}).type || window.screen.mozOrientation || window.screen.msOrientation;

  if (["landscape-primary","landscape-secondary"].indexOf(orientation) !== -1) {
    becomeFullscreen();
  } else if (orientation === undefined) {
    console.log("The orientation API isn't supported in this browser :("); 
  }
});
```